# Send an email to $row_data['email']

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have user verify page where the admin can approve or disapprove users. All that codes functions well, but except for email part where once the admin approve the user account...the user suppose to received an email to notified. The user's email address should be taken from the database.

```
<?php
    include('../setting/config.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "select * from `register_requests` where `id` = '$id'; ";
    if(count(fetchAll($query)) > 0){
        foreach(fetchAll($query) as $row){
            $email = $row['email'];
            $level = $row['level'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $password = $row['password'];
            $query = "INSERT INTO `registered_accounts` (`id`, `email`, `level`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$email', '$level', '$username', '$password');";
        }
        $query .= "DELETE FROM `register_requests` WHERE `register_requests`.`id` = '$id';";
        if(performQuery($query)){
            echo "<script>alert('This account has been approved');window.location.href='View_Users.php';</script>";
        }
         $sql = "SELECT email FROM register_requests";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        while ($row_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $from = 'emarketing.unisel.faudzi.info';
        $to = $row_data['email']; 
        $subject = 'Sample Form';
        $msg = 'Hello world!';
        mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
        
    }
}
    
?>
```

Please assist on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
while ($row_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

use

```
while ($row_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: Hi @bob_1982 do I need to replace my mail() code to the given code?

Comment: Earlier I tried with $to and then I put my email address to test. I able to received the email but after I put to capture the email address from database, it doesn't works

Comment: you are using fetch in wrong way. let me edit my answer that may help you

Comment: Hey @bob_1982 still not receiving any email after edited the code.

Comment: Anyone to assist on this ?

Comment: you can do two things.1. execute query "SELECT email FROM register_requests" manually to see if this is giving any results. 2. in while statement use print_r($row_data) to see what the row_data contains